# Angular 10 Google index only first page?

Tags: angular, single-page-application

I have an angular app. It is csr.
I update dynamicly title, description, keywords tags.

But google index only first page for 1 month.

I dont want to move app to ssr.

How can I fix this?

https://www.kitapcisepeti.com/

Comment: By moving your app to SSR :)

Answer (score 0):

Your homepage doesn't have any links in it, even on CSR. The way Google works is, it follows links to index web pages. Since your homepage doesn't have any links, that's the only thing Google is able to index.

Your entire content seems to be hidden behind the search box.

You might want to read up on SEO and implement various SEO strategies. For starters, you could create something like "recent searches" with links to perform searches.

But to get the full benefit of SEO, it is highly recommended to enable SSR on your app.

Comment: I added links to home. removed hash from url. added sitemap to search console. but still same for 1 day.

Comment: @erenarslan Reindexing CSR content takes time. If SEO is important, you should really consider SSR. Meanwhile, if the answer helped in any way, consider upvoting. Thanks!